# How can I move an SCNNode in SceneKit, but affected by gravity?

Tags: scenekit, shapes, gravity, scnnode

`SCNAction.move(to:SCNVector3)` doesn't work. It moves the shape but the shape doesn't fall.

There's some other action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you'll need to give your SCNNode a physicsBody and configure it prior to adding the node to the scene.

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType, shape: SCNPhysicsShape)
myNode.physicsBody = body
```

Then you can set the .isAffectedByGravity property to true.

```
myNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = true
```

Now, when you add the node to the scene, it will fall.